# How to implement a real Singleton in Scala

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, singleton

I have mixed Java/Scala project. There are Quartz jobs that are implemented in Java and use some Scala classes. These classes should use the same SparkContext instance, so I implemented something that should be singleton and looks like this:

```
object SparkContextLoader {
    var hasSC = false
    var sc:Any = 0
    def getSC(workers):SparkContext={
    if (!hasSC) {
        val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[" + workers + "]").setAppName("SparkApp")
        sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
        hasSC = true
    }
    return sc.asInstanceOf[SparkContext]
}
```

Calling SparkContextLoader from two different jobs always creates a new SparkContext instance which is not allowed.

Why Scala object doesn't behave like singleton?

Comment: are your quartz jobs written in java? and did you review how to reference scala objects in java code?

Comment: also you are using a var instead of a val for the SparkContext

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use a Scala singleton object in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12284028/how-can-i-use-a-scala-singleton-object-in-java)

Comment: @4e6 It's not duplicate with this. If you check my post, it's I'm not using Scala singleton object from Java. Java jobs create instances of some Scala classes and call a function on that classes. These scala classes use Scala object that should behave as Singleton, i.e. to return one SparkContext instance for the whole application.

Comment: As suggested by @heavyhorse  the problem was that I was using var instead of val for SparkContext

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is overly complicated.  If the "two different jobs" are different threads then all you need is:

```
object SparkContextLoader {

  val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[" + workers + "]").setAppName("SparkApp")

  val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
}
```

You can then access these vals using the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12284028/how-can-i-use-a-scala-singleton-object-in-java).

If the "two different jobs" are different java applications then [it doesn't seem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17721263/singleton-across-jvm-or-application-instance-or-tomcat-instance) that there is a way to share a singleton across both of them.

Comment: You were right. Using var instead of val for SparkContext was the problem. I expected scala object would always behave like Singleton, but it's obviously not the case.